# Cordova APP - Is it possible to show camera feed in a container?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionicFramework with Cordova to build an App. My requirement is to show (front) camera feed inside my app (say at top right corner of the app).

Unfortunately "cordovaCapture" is not working for me. "navigator.camera" just opens camera view, but my requirement is to show its feed in a container so its also not fitting in requirement.

I tried backgroundvideo plugin also.

Please help me in understanding, Is it possible to access camera feed without going native app approach ? Please share any leads.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show me which plugin are you using and your camera options which you are requesting .

Answer (score 2):

I'll just point you to the right direction:

1. https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview
2. https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin

Try these plugins (in order) and lemme know if either of them worked out for you.

Comment: But these plugins offer capturing image not video.
How can I record video this way?

Comment: Can't find any way for you to record video this way. What's your use case anyway?

Comment: At most, I'd probably try taking lots of pictures (of lesser height-width) in quick succession then stitching them back up to create a video through some other mechanism; but I guess it would take up a LOT of resources.

Comment: Yes that is one option but that may make my app slow. Actually its my client's requirement to show video inside app instead of in external native window.

Comment: If you want BOTH the capturing and playback of the video inside a container in your app, then I guess you'd have to create a plugin of your own/ go native.

It might still be possible if the capturing would be done _outside_ your app and playback inside.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.